# Sort csv file by three columns using command with null value?

Tags: windows, sorting, csv, batch-file, command-line

The case is like this :

I have a csv file with 6 columns without header like below :

```
5002200,25081,0000002797,6,,2014/06/05
5001111,25081,0000002790,,,2014/06/05
5004901,00081,0000002799,5,,2014/06/05 
5004901,00081,0000002796,5,,2014/06/05
```

The output I want is after sorted and displayed like below:

```
5001111,25081,0000002790,,,2014/06/05
5002200,25081,0000002797,6,,2014/06/05  
5004901,00081,0000002796,5,,2014/06/05 
5004901,00081,0000002799,5,,2014/06/05
```

```
@echo off
if not exist %1 goto :EOF
setlocal
for /F "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%a in (%1) do set "a[%%b,%%c,%%a,%%d,%%e,%%f]=[]"
break > %1
for /F "tokens=2-7 delims=[,]=" %%a in ('set a[') do echo %%c,%%a,%%b,%%d,%%e,%%f>> %1
endlocal
```

The problem is the null value would missing. Any idea?

My algorithm is sort the 1st columns and 3nd columns then display as original position. But if there are any empty value(like 4th or 5th columns), it would missed. 

First column always contains 7 length.

Only 4th or 5th column would contains empty.

Comment: why do you split into tokens, if you don't use the single tokens? Use the wholel line instead.

Comment: I am new in cmd script. Would you please show me? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sort /+8 infilename >outfilename
```

would appear to do what you want. Perhaps if you were to explain clearly what your sorting algorithm is, we'd be able to construct a more suitable system.

---

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q36542742.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET "tempfile=%destdir%\tempfile.txt"
DEL "%tempfile%" >NUL 2>NUL  
(
:: first step - number each line, number to %%a, line to %%b
FOR /f "skip=1tokens=1*delims=[]" %%a IN ('find /n /v "" "%filename1%"') DO (
 REM tokenise line - required parts to  %%p, %%q
 FOR /f "tokens=1,3delims=," %%p IN ("%%b") DO (
  REM construct sort-record
  CALL :process %%p%%q %%a "%%b"
 )
)
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims= " %%a IN ('sort "%tempfile%"') DO ECHO(%%b
)>"%outfile%"

DEL "%tempfile%" >NUL 2>NUL  

GOTO :EOF

:: First parameter: primary sort-criterion (fixed-length)
:: Second : secondary sort-criterion (leadin-zero-suppressed numeric)
:: Third : quoted data
:process
SET /a $line=1000000000+%2
>>"%tempfile%" ECHO(%1%$line% %~3
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q36542742.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

`tempfile` can be set to whatever takes your fancy.

First, send the file trough `find` looking for lines that don't contain *nothing* and number them. Each line will thus become

```
[number]originallinedata
```

and by tokenising on `[]` using the fact that each line begins with a numeric, `%%a` will be set as the line-number and `%%b` as the line-data.

Reprocess the line-data, using `,` to tokenise and pick tokens 1 and 3. Both fields are of fixed-length and the second token may not be empty.

Process the line through the procedure `:process` providing the parameters *concatenated_column1_column3* *line_number* *originaldataline*

Within `:process`, add 1000000000 to the line-number in `%2`, then send

*concatenated_column1_column3_modified_line_number*<kbd>Space</kbd>*originaldataline*

So the line sent would be

```
500220000000027971000000001 5002200,25081,0000002797,6,,2014/06/05
```

The line-portion before the space is fixed-length.

When done, sort the tempfile and report the part after the first space.

Comment: Also, first columns is not always contains 8 length.

Answer (score 0):

Just 1 line with sort of Unxutil commands if input file and output file are different,

```
gawk -F"," "{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}" input.csv|sort -gk1,3|sed "s/ /,/g";"s/$/\r/">output.csv
```

If the output is to input file directly, for example, input .csv file can get the result by dragging itself to the batch-file,

```
sed -i "s/,/ /g" "%~1"
sort -gk1,3 "%~1" -o"%~1"
sed -i "s/ /,/g";"s/$/\r/" "%~1"
exit /b
```

Each columns can be kept as original.

Answer (score 0):

The following script is capable of what you are requesting (let us call it `sort-csv.bat`):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define constants:
set "INFILE=%~1"
set "OUTFILE=%~2"
set "TEMPFILE=%TEMP%\%~n1_interim_to_sort%~x1"
set /A MAXWIDTH=10

if not exist "!INFILE!" exit /B 1
if not defined OUTFILE set "OUTFILE=%~dpn1_sorted%~x1"
set "PADZEROS="
for /L %%$ in (1,1,%MAXWIDTH%) do set "PADZEROS=!PADZEROS!0"
> "!TEMPFILE!" (
    for /F "delims=" %%# in ('findstr /N /R "^^" "!INFILE!"') do (
        set "LINE=%%#" & set "LINE=!LINE:*:=!"
        for /F "delims=:" %%a in ("%%#") do set "LNUM=!PADZEROS!%%a"
        for /F "tokens=1,3 delims=," %%A in (""!LINE:^,^=","!"") do (
            set "ITEM1=!PADZEROS!%%~A" & set "ITEM1=!ITEM1:~-%MAXWIDTH%!"
            set "ITEM2=!PADZEROS!%%~B" & set "ITEM2=!ITEM2:~-%MAXWIDTH%!"
            echo(!ITEM1!;!ITEM2!;!LNUM:~-%MAXWIDTH%!_!LINE!
        )
    )
)
> "!OUTFILE!" (
    for /F "tokens=1,* delims=_" %%I in ('sort "!TEMPFILE!"') do (
        echo(%%J
    )
)
> nul 2>&1 del "!TEMPFILE!"

endlocal
exit /B
```

To use this batch file, provide the input and output paths/files as command line arguments:

> ```
> sort-csv.bat "input-file.csv" "output-file.csv"
> ```

The main idea behind this is to replace every single separator `,` by `","` and enclosing every line within `""`, so each item becomes enclosed within `""`; for instance, a line like `1,2,,4` becomes `"1","2","","4"`. This avoids adjacent separators `,,` and therefore, a `for /F` loop with `,` as the delimiter can be used to get the items; the `~` modifier of the `for /F` variable is used to remove the surrounding `""`.

For sorting, a temporary file is used, which contains the original lines prefixed with the (semicolon-separated) columns to be used for sorting and the original line number in a leading-zero-padded manner. So your input file becomes this:

> ```
> 0005002200;0000002797;0000000001_5002200,25081,0000002797,6,,2014/06/05
> 0005001111;0000002790;0000000002_5001111,25081,0000002790,,,2014/06/05
> 0005004901;0000002799;0000000003_5004901,00081,0000002799,5,,2014/06/05
> 0005004901;0000002796;0000000004_5004901,00081,0000002796,5,,2014/06/05
> ```

This file is then fed into the `sort` command, whose output is captured by another `for /F` loop, which cuts off the prefix, that is everything up to the `_` character.

Comment: What do you mean? does the script produce no output file? it works for me, using your sample data; note that I fixed the script file name (it is called `sort-csv.bat` instead of `sort_csv.bat`)...

Comment: I fix it. but could you please edit some code to let input is one file, output is sorted in those file.

Comment: To overwrite the original file, just give the same file as input and output file; for instance: `sort-csv.bat "datafile.csv" "datafile.csv"`; if you want the script to accept a single argument only, simply replace the line `set "OUTFILE=%~2"` (line #6) by `set "OUTFILE=%~1"`, or even better, replace line #11 `if not defined OUTFILE set "OUTFILE=%~dpn1_sorted%~x1"` by `if not defined OUTFILE set "OUTFILE=%~f1"` (so you could still provide a second argument as the outpu file optionally)...

Comment: After some testing, your script has a bug when process some rows have same content in 1st columns and different in 3nd columns. There are another row being missed.

Comment: @Kason, please explain what happens; with the sample data you provided, the script works fine; so could you please give sample data which cause the script to fail?

Comment: I cannot find a place to add the data, just edited to your answer.

Comment: why not to use `Unxutil` command?  It's common GNU utilities of UNIX to native Windows. One command line can completely solve your question.

Comment: @Kason, although your [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/2453260) has been rejected, I could get your new 5-row data; however, I cannot reproduce the problem you described, the output of my script is 5 correctly sorted rows; did you copy the script as is, or did you modify it somehow? please re-check; what command line are you using?

Comment: Finally, I found out that my script skips the last line of the inut file when it is not terminated by a line-break; in the command line part `findstr /N /R "^$" "!INFILE!"`, the `"^$"` part is wrong, it should be `"^^"` I think; I corrected that -- see my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36555615/6)...